# Using AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient GetParameters fails

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have a Lambda in C# and I'm trying to access parameters stored in the ECQ Parameter Store. The parameters are stored as a String Value.

My Lambda is configured to use an existing role. In IAM, I've assigned the following policies to the role:

- AmazonRedshiftReadOnlyAccess
- AmazonKinesisReadOnlyAccess
- AmazonVPCFullAccess
- AWSLambdaExecute
- AmazonSSMReadOnlyAccess
- AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole

The Lambda runs inside of our VPC and if the parameter value is hard-coded it executes successfully.

My code to get the parameter is:

```
var client = new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient(RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2);
var request = new GetParametersRequest
{
   Names = new List<string>{ "ParameterName" }
};
var response = client.GetParametersAsync(request).Result;
var value = response.Parameters.Single().Value;
```

I have logging before and after the call to GetParametersAsync and it doesn't get to the logging after the call.

What do I need to do to be able to get the parameter value from the Lambda?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue was caused by the Lambda running inside of our VPC. Accessing SSM is done via the internet so I had to configure a NAT Gateway to give the Lambda access to the internet.

Once this was done, the Lambda could access the SSM parameters successfully.

Comment: If you don't want/need to open up all outbound traffic for your Lambda functions that run in your VPC, you can set up an [Interface VPC Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpce-interface.html) for SSM instead of a NAT Gateway, Internet Gateway, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should have something similar to:

```
public async Task<Response> ProcessS3ImageResizeAsync(SimpleS3Event input)
{
   var response = await client.DoAsyncWork(input);
   return response;
}
```

In async call the response is not immediate, thus you need to wait before.

More information:

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dotnet-programming-model-handler-types.html#dot-net-async

Comment: Example is directly from my source, needs modifications to suit your case. It should not be a big deal, once the idea is so simple.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code I have works when run via Visual Studio using my personal access key. It doesn’t work running within lambda - I believe it’s an IAM issue but can’t figure it out.

Comment: Good that you found an answer. Thinking more the case, await is used inside the GetParametersAsync, not when calling it.